# Write list of objects to s3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I have a list of objects that I want to write to s3. I am using the following code:

```
    Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
    S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder()
            .region(region)
            .build();

    for (Event event: events){

      final ByteBufferOutputStream serializedEvent = serialize(event);
      if (serializedEvent == null) {
        continue;
      }
      PutObjectRequest objectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
              .bucket(bucket)
              .key(path)
              .build();
      s3Client.putObject(objectRequest, RequestBody.fromByteBuffer(serializedEvent.toByteBuffer()));
    }


  public String getS3Path(String bucket){

    String year = Integer.toString(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).getYear());
    String month = Integer.toString(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).getMonthValue());
    String day = Integer.toString(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).getDayOfMonth());
    String hour = Integer.toString(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).getHour());

    return bucket+"/"+year+"/"+month+"/"+day+"/"+hour+"/";

  }

  private ByteBufferOutputStream serialize(final Object object) {
    try {
      final ByteBufferOutputStream outputStream = new ByteBufferOutputStream(128, true, false);
      Json.writeValueAsToOutputStream(object, outputStream);
      outputStream.write('\n');
      return outputStream;
    }
    catch (final Exception e) {
      log.error("Error serializing data {}", object, e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

I want to add a delimitter '\n' after every object such that it could be read by Athena and I can query the json data. Any ideas how can I achieve tha ?

EDIT: I am appending '\n' but this write each event individually. I want to upload Event as a batch and each json delimitted by '\n'

Comment: `String.join("\n", events)`?

Comment: update your question with full script that includes writing to file